# Pass data to excel file having macros using asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

I want to export excel file, which is on IIS which contains graph and other data. What I need is that when user click on export, data need to pass to that excel file and then it is exported to client on client machin using asp.net application. I just want to know that how I can pass data to excels file having macros.

Comment: What code do you have at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code (You can use Interop)

```
            var oExcel = new ApplicationClass();


            var oBook = oBooks.Open("c:\\test.xls", oMissing, oMissing,
                oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, 
                oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

            // Launch the macros (his name is Run).
            RunMacro(oExcel, new Object[]{"arg1", "arg2"});

            // Quit Excel and clean up.
            oBook.Close(false, oMissing, oMissing);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject (oBook);
            oExcel.Quit();



And function in order to launch macro

 private void RunMacro(object oApp, object[] oRunArgs)
            {

                oApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oApp, oRunArgs);
            }
```